# How to serialize deep and shallow in pydantic?

Tags: python, serialization, pydantic

I'm using Pydantic for my data models, and I sometimes need to serialize them deep (i.e. including all children), but for complex structures that gets pretty big, so I also need an API that only provides one level of the hierarchy shallowly. Example:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_serializer, FieldSerializationInfo

# Option 1: Serialize deep
class B1(BaseModel):
    id: str
    value:int

class A1(BaseModel):
    id: str
    kids: List[B1]

a1 = A1(id="A11", kids=[B1(id="B11", value=123), B1(id="B12", value=456)])
print("Deep: ", a1.model_dump())

# Option 2: Serialize shallow
class B2(BaseModel):
    id: str
    value:int

class A2(BaseModel):
    id: str
    kids: List[B2]

    @field_serializer('kids')
    def ser_kids(self, kids: List[B2], _info:FieldSerializationInfo):
        return [k.id for k in kids]

a2 = A2(id="A21", kids=[B2(id="B21", value=123), B2(id="B22", value=456)])
print("Shallow: ", a2.model_dump())

# Option 3: Serialize shallow (JSON only)
class B3(BaseModel):
    id: str
    value:int

class A3(BaseModel):
    id: str
    kids: List[B3]

    @field_serializer('kids', when_used='json')
    def ser_kids(self, kids: List[B3], _info):
        return [k.id for k in kids]

a3 = A3(id="A31", kids=[B3(id="B31", value=123), B3(id="B32", value=456)])
print("Deep(dict): ", a3.model_dump())
print("Shallow(JSON): ", a3.model_dump_json())
```

Output:

```
Deep:  {'id': 'A11', 'kids': [{'id': 'B11', 'value': 123}, {'id': 'B12', 'value': 456}]}
Shallow:  {'id': 'A21', 'kids': ['B21', 'B22']}
Deep(dict):  {'id': 'A31', 'kids': [{'id': 'B31', 'value': 123}, {'id': 'B32', 'value': 456}]}
Shallow(JSON):  {"id":"A31","kids":["B31","B32"]}
```

I can do it as in the example using a `field_serializer`, but I'm not sure how to switch between deep and shallow on the fly without duplicating all classes. The only way I could find is using JSON vs. non-JSON as in example 3, but sometimes I do want a deep JSON version.

Is there any way to switch this on the fly? The `field_serializer` gets the `_info` field with some options, but I can't see where that's created or how to customize it.

Thanks!